# How to show badges in d3 forced direct vertex

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas

In d3 forced layout vertex which is rendered using canvas , how to add badge which shows number count. Something Like . Can I add shapes inside circle shape and attach.

[image]

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/gapitukinu/edit?html,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Graph Rendring Using Canvas</title>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/gka/randomgraph.js/master/randomgraph.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var graph = randomgraph.WattsStrogatz.beta(15, 4, 0.06);

var canvas = null;
var width = window.innerWidth,
height = window.innerHeight;
canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

force = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
            return d.index;
        })).force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

force.nodes(graph.nodes);
force.force("link").links(graph.edges).distance(200);

var detachedContainer = document.createElement("custom");
dataContainer = d3.select(detachedContainer);

link = dataContainer.selectAll(".link").data(graph.edges)
    .enter().append("line").attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)

    node = dataContainer.selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "node node_" + d.index;
    })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", 'red')
    .attr("strokeStyle", 'black');

d3.timer(function () {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // draw links
    link.each(function (d) {
        context.beginPath();

        context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
        context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);

        context.closePath();

        context.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
        context.stroke();
    });

    context.lineWidth = 2;
    node.each(function (d) {

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(d.x, d.y);
        var r = this.getAttribute('r');

        d.x = Math.max(30, Math.min(width - 30, d.x));
        d.y = Math.max(30, Math.min(height - 30, d.y));

        context.arc(d.x, d.y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = this.getAttribute('fill');
        context.strokeStyle = this.getAttribute('strokeStyle');

        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    });

});

node.transition().duration(5000).attr('r', 20).attr('fill', 'orange');

canvas.node().addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // Its COMING ANY TIME INSIDE ON CLICK OF CANVAS
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest using `g` in your data join. So instead of appending `circle` straight away after your `.enter()` use `g` elements, position their `x` and `y` in your force timer function. You can then easily append a circle and any other elements to that group for showing labels and more. Initially positioning the `g` element instead of the `circle` makes sure they all get positioned correctly.`

Comment: Can you give me example of something similar , I am new to d3 @AntonvB

Comment: Have a look at this example -> https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642. It's positioning an icon and label for each force point. Very similar to what you are trying to do. You will see that they append an svg group element in the data enter and then append circles and labels to that group itself.

Comment: Will this will work in case of canvas also

Comment: No probably not. Do you have to use canvas?

Comment: I am trying , will you help me with more input @AntonvB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First add a group like this:

```
node = dataContainer.selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes)
              .enter().append("g");
```

Next to the group add circle like this.

```
  var circles = node.append("circle")
      .classed("circle-class", true)
      .attr("class", function (d){ return "node node_" + d.index;})
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", 'red')
      .attr("strokeStyle", 'black');
```

Next add transition to the circles like this:

```
circles.transition().duration(5000).attr('r', 20).attr('fill', 'orange');
```

Next in the timer where you redraw your canvas.
Make circle
Make text within the circle.

```
  //make the small circle
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(d.x + 15, d.y-20, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);//circle with fixed radius of 5
  context.fillStyle = "orange";
  context.strokeStyle = "orange";
  //get the data from the group
  var data = d3.select(this).data();
  context.stroke();
  context.fill();
  context.font = "10px Arial";
  context.fillStyle = "black";
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  //write the text in the context
  context.fillText(parseInt(data[0].index),d.x + 10, d.y-15);
```

working code [here](http://jsbin.com/xaqolexupi/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Your answer is amazing ,  I am thinking of two problem i can face with this , what if number size is big , how to accommodate automatically .

Comment: That you will need to program the x for text by looking at the string 's length.

Comment: Do you know how can I add arrow to edge